# How do I code buttons for an applet involving calculating cost of shipping?

Tags: java, swing

I am coding an applet where the user can choose checkboxes in a GUI for which items they would like to purchase, choose the type of shipping that they wish to pay for, and calculate the payment with or without shipping.

---

So far this is the code I have created for it:

```
private void withShippingActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

}                                            

private void withoutShippingActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
   if (withShipping.isSelected()){

   }
}                                               

public double prices(double order, double computer, double printer, double speaker, double headphones, double mouse, double extrakeyboard, double flashdrive){
    order = 0;
    computer = 275;
    printer = 50;
    speaker = 25;
    headphones = 15;
    mouse = 10;
    extrakeyboard = 30;
    flashdrive = 10;

    return order;
}
public double calculateCost() { //calculates price of computer with extra
    if (extraKeyboard.isSelected()){
        return computer += 30;
        }

    if (flashDrive.isSelected()){
        return computer += 10; 
        }

    if (headphones.isSelected()){
        return computer += 15;
        } 

    if (mouse.isSelected()){
        return computer += 10;
        }

    if (printer.isSelected()){
        return computer += 50;
        }

        if (speaker.isSelected()){
        return computer += 25;
        } 
    return order;
}

public double calculateCost(int quantity, boolean shipping) {                                                
    quantity = 1;
    double order = calculateCost();

    if (ground.isSelected() || air.isSelected() || fedex.isSelected()) {
    shipping = true;
    if (shipping == true) {
        {
            if (ground.isSelected()) {
                while (quantity >= 100) {
                    return calculateCost() * 0.05;
                }
            }
            if (air.isSelected()) {
                return calculateCost() * 0.10;
            }
            if (fedex.isSelected()) {
                return calculateCost() * 0.20;
} 
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }

private double order = 0;
private double computer = 275.0;

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JRadioButton air;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox extraKeyboard;
private javax.swing.JLabel extraPurchases;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton fedex;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox flashDrive;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton ground;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox headphones;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox mouse;
private javax.swing.JLabel paymentChoiceLabel;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox printer;
private javax.swing.JLabel shippingDirections;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup shippinggroup;
private javax.swing.JCheckBox speaker;
private javax.swing.JLabel total;
private javax.swing.JButton withShipping;
private javax.swing.JButton withoutShipping;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

---

Now, my question is: How do I code the "with shipping" and "without shipping" buttons so that they calculate the total cost with the shipping or without the shipping and displays a table for the cost of 1 unit, 100 units, 200 units, up to 1000 units. The question asks for two columns and based on my display in my GUI I do not understand how I would do that as well.

Comment: TLDR; Well. Your question is really long (nobody will read it). Can you reduce your question providing the relevant parts? Read [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just reading your code, `public double prices` probably does not do what you want, and then it just returns 0

Comment: And as far as *I believe my calculate cost methods are correct* -- This is something that *unit testing* should be used for.

Comment: What is unit testing?

Comment: *"I have given myself the task of coding an applet.."* Make it an application. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).